# Перегрузка функций в СИ (не сработал дженерик макрос)

Tags: c

В общем знаю что в СИ нету перегрузок функции. Но есть подключаемый заголовочный файл `#include <stdarg.h>` и дженерик макросы.

В общем попробовал простейший код , но почему то он не запуститься :( 
Побывал через дженерик макросы (так как у меня "последний" си, они у меня работают), через `stdarg.h` сложна, я так и не понял как через него работать.

вот код :

```
int Summa2(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

int Summa3(int x, int y, int z){
    return x+y+z;
}

#define Summa(X, Y, Z) _Generic((X), (Y), (Z)\
    Generic((X), (Y)\
    Summa2() \
    ),\
    Summa3() \
)(X, Y, Z)

//static int Summa(int x, int y, ...){

//}

int main()
{
    printf("Summa(2,2) : %d\n", Summa(2,2));
    printf("Summa(3,3,3) : %d\n", Summa(3,3,3));

    return 0;
}
```

Что я сделал не так ??

---

попробовал "иную" реализацию

```
  int Summa(int x, int y, int z = 0 ){
        return x+y+z;
    }

  int main()
    {
        printf("Summa(2,2) : %d\n", Summa(2,2));
        printf("Summa(3,3,3) : %d\n", Summa(3,3,3));

        return 0;
    }
```

Увы пишет две ошибки (первая ошибка)

```
  ошибка: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
 int Summa(int x, int y, int z =0 ){
                               ^
```

(вторая ошибка)

```
 ошибка: too few arguments to function ‘Summa’
     printf("Summa(2,2) : %d\n", Summa(2,2));
                                 ^~~~~
```

Увы но в сиси нет значения по умолчанию :(

Comment: Что это за белиберда и при чем здесь `<stdarg.h>` вообще? Что такое `Generic`? `_Generic` осуществляет выбор по типу. Где у вас выбор по типу?

Comment: @AnT А как сделать ??  чтоб выполнял ??

Comment: "Чтобы выполнял" **что**? "Перегрузку" по количеству аргументов через `_Generic` сделать не получится.

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @AnT мне достался код где есть вызов функции  то  с двумя то с тремя параметрами , сама функция мне не досталась. но  программа так и библиотека(к которой и  относится та функция про которую я говорю) написаны на си

Comment: Это действительно можно сделать через `<stdarg.h>`, но ключевым моментом здесь является именно то, что каким-то образом внутри функции вы должны уметь узнать, сколько параметров вам передали. Ни язык, ни стандартная библиотека сами по себе не помогут вам узнать количество параметров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом деле, предложенный в одном из ответов вариант с функцией, получающей массив и его размер, самый простой и поэтому хороший.

Остается лишь синтаксически привлекательно оформить его. На такой случай  в Си-препроцессоре есть [Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

В первом приближении получаем примерно такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// функция, реально вычисляющая сумму
int
_a_sum (size_t n, int a[]) {
  int s = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    s += a[i];

  return s;
}


// вот такой макрос делает скобочное выражение, в котором создается временный
// массив, инициализируемый при выполнении (не компиляции)
// и возвращается результат функции суммирования его элементов
#define Sum(t, ...) ({ __typeof__(t) _a[] = { t, __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  _a_sum(sizeof(_a) / sizeof(_a[0]), _a);})

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int sum = Sum(1, 2, 3);

  if (sum < Sum(1, 2, 3, 4))
    printf("%d %d\n", sum, Sum(1, 2, sum, 3, 4));

  printf("%d\n", Sum(ac));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Как видите, он покрывает большинство разумных случаев использования.

Наверняка, повозившись с `_Generic` (но это уже не [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) за 5 минут), можно сделать и генерацию имени функции с суффиксом (или префиксом) в зависимости от типа данных.

Answer (score 4):

Добиться перегрузки по количеству аргументов через макросы можно, но в реальном коде так делать не стоит.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum2(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

int sum3(int x, int y, int z){
    return x+y+z;
}

#define CAT(x,y) CAT_(x,y)
#define CAT_(x,y) x##y
#define VA_COUNT(...) VA_COUNT_(__VA_ARGS__,3,2,1,0)
#define VA_COUNT_(x3,x2,x1,x0,...) x0

#define sum(...) CAT(sum,VA_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sum(1,2)); // 3
    printf("%d\n", sum(1,2,3)); // 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@AnT навёл на ответ. 
Но, все таки весьма своеобразно ибо все равно один параметр, в моём случае первый, выполняет роль "датчика", передающего количество отправленных элементов.

В заголовочном файле подключаем

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// Для функции с переменным количеством аргументов подключ stdarg stdlib
#include <stdarg.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>   

int Summa(int count,...);
```

В файле main.c

```
int Summa(int count,...){
    int s=0; //перем. для  записи результата

    va_list p; //обявл. указ. на аргументы функции
    va_start(p,count); // устан. указатель на первый анонимный агрумент

    while(count){ // вычисление суммы
        s += va_arg(p,int);
        count--;
    }

    va_end(p); // завершение раб. с анонимными аргументами

    return s; 
}

int main()
{
    printf("Summa(1,1) : %d\n", Summa(2,1,1));
    printf("Summa(3,6,3) : %d\n", Summa(3,3,6,3));

    return 0;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно и так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int args[], int size) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", args[i]);
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int args[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    func(args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Передавать аргументы массивом... дёшего и сердито как говорится