# Перегрузка макроса по числу параметров

Tags: c++, c99

Я хочу написать макрос FOO, так чтобы FOO(x) и FOO(x, y) делали разные вещи.
Как это сделать?

Comment: См. ответ HolyBlackCat: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956656/182825

Answer (score 3):

Вариант для Clang и GCC:

Определяем два макроса с разным количеством аргументов

```
#define FOO_1(x) x*100
#define FOO_2(a, b) a*b
```

Пишем вспомогательный макрос, который возвращает 3й переданный параметр. Он будет выбирать один из двух макросов выше.

```
#define FOO_SELECT(_1, _2, macro, ...) macro
#define FOO(...) FOO_SELECT(__VA_ARGS__, FOO_2, FOO_1, dummy)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Если было передан один аргумент, то `FOO_SELECT(1, FOO_2, FOO_1, dummy)` раскроется в `FOO_1`.
Для двух аргументов `FOO_SELECT(1, 2, FOO_2, FOO_1, dummy)` раскроется в `FOO_2`.

Comment: `FOO_2, FOO_1, dummy)(__VA_ARGS__)` иначе будет `ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro` То бишь `...` нельзя оставлять пустым